# Passing a preset to babel programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

I'm struggling to use `babel` programmatically.

```
"use strict";

const babel = require("babel-core")
    , es2015 = require("babel-preset-es2015")
    ;

babel.transformFile("my-file.js", {
   presets: [es2015]
}, (err, result) =>
  console.log(err || result)
);
```

This ends with this error:

> `Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/Users/myusername"`

Though, I did install the `babel-preset-es2015` as local dependency. How to fix this?

I don't want to keep `babel-preset-es2015` and `babel-core` as local dependencies of the project.

Why does this error appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I started debugging deep in the `babel-core` and found a check for `opts.babelrc !== false`.

I probably have a `.babelrc` in my home directory, but since I want to use `babel` programmatically, I just want to ignore it, so I use `babelrc: false` in the options:

```
"use strict";

const babel = require("babel-core")
    , es2015 = require("babel-preset-es2015")
    ;

babel.transformFile("my-file.js", {
   presets: [es2015]
 , babelrc: false
}, (err, result) =>
  console.log(err || result)
);
```

Comment: `.babelrc` files belong in the project folder, you should never have a `.babelrc` in a generic parent folder, that's asking for trouble, just like this case.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Yes, true. Because I don't really want to have project-specific babel configuration, I created [`babel-it`](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/babel-it) which just babelifies the code in the current directory, before `npm publish`.